# How to fix incomplete type of struct

Tags: c

Basically I'm running this code on this CLion application due to my teacher's demands.

I have my struct of 'Estado' defined in .c file like this:

```
struct estado{

    char modo;
    char jogador;
    char matriz[8][8];
    int pretas;
    int brancas;

};
```

And have this on my .h file:

```
typedef struct estado* Estado;
```

In my main.c file where i try to acess:

```
printf("%s",novo -> matriz[1]);
```

It says: "error : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct estado' "

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `struct` declaration in your `.h` file instead of the `.c` file.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia What do you mean? Doing it should fix your error.

Comment: I mean i can create the struct in the .c file, and have it on the .h file and work just fine, did it already once just like this

Comment: if `main.c` doesn't have access the definition of `struct estado`, then it can not figure out how to  access `matriz`.   Your current header only says that there is a struct, not how it is constructed.   There are some cases where you can get away with only having a pointer to an incomplete type, but dereferencing them is not one such case.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia To mark question as solved, pick an answer that helped you the most, and press the green tick to the left of it. Also, a tip: when replying to someone's comment (not under their own post) use `@username`; otherwise the user might not receive a notification.

Comment: @LeonardoMaia You say that you have done this before. I think that what you did before is slightly different than your example here. I suggest that you look closely to find the differences. Or if you can't see them, then post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define the struct in the header, you'll end up with an *opaque* pointer, so that whatever is inside that struct is hidden from other translation units.

You can always declare some accessor functions in the header

```
typedef struct estado Estado; // <- Not a pointer

Estado *alloc_estado(void);
void print_row(Estado *e, int i);
// ...
```

Define those in the `.c` file

```
#include "estado.h"

struct estado
{
    char modo;
    char jogador;
    char matriz[8][8];
    int pretas;
    int brancas;
};

void print_row(Estado *e, int i)
{
    printf("%s\n", e->matriz[i]);
}
// ...
```

And use in `main`

```
#include "estado.h"

int main(void)
{
    Estado *pes = alloc_estado();
    // ...
    print_row(pes, 1);
    // ...
    free(pes);
}
```